# Using DataAnnotations/IValidatable object on a model passed to server via AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

**Warning: Long Question!  There's a lot of setup to get to what I need to ask.**

So, I'm working on a small experiment project, because I'm trying to figure out **if** I can trigger server-side MVC validation on a model that was sent to the server via AJAX.  The experiment app takes a note name, sign, and octave, to determine the frequency of the note.

My view is pretty standard:

```
<div id='frequency-line-container'>
    // By default, nothing...
</div>

<div id='new-line-interface'>
    <p>
        What note is sounding?  <input type='text' id='note-name' maxlength='1' />
    </p>

    <p>
        What sign is by the note?

        <span>
            @Html.RadioButton("note-sign", "natural", true, new {id="note-natural"})Natural 
            @Html.RadioButton("note-sign", "sharp", false, new {id="note-sharp"})Sharp
            @Html.RadioButton("note-sign", "flat", false, new {id="note-flat"})Flat
        </span>
    <p>

    <p>
        What octave is the note sounding at?  <input type='number' id='octave' maxlength='1' min='0' max='9' />
    </p>

    <a href='#' id='save-button'>Save</a>
</div>
```

On the client, I have the following JavaScript set up:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $frequencyLineContainer = $('#frequency-line-container'),
        $saveLineButton = $('#save-line'),
        $noteName = $('#note-name'),
        $octave = $('#octave');

    $saveLineButton.click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var data = getLineData();
        var $promise = getNewLinePromise(data, true);
        $.when($promise)
            .then(addLine);
    });

    function getLineData() {
        var $noteSign = $('#note-sign-section input[type="radio"][name="note-sign"]:checked');
        var model = {
            'NoteName': $noteName.val(),
            'NoteSign': $noteSign.val(),
            'Octave': parseInt($octave.val())
        };

        return {
            'model': model
        };
    }

    function getNewLinePromise(data, async) {
        return $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Home/AddFrequencyLine/',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: data,
            async: async
        });
    }

    function addLine(result) {
        $frequencyLineContainer.append(result);
    }
});
```

...and on the server, my action is pretty simple:

```
[HttpPost]
public void AddFrequencyLine(FrequencyLineViewModel model)
{
    model.CalculateFrequency();  // Determines the frequency of a note by sign, name, and octave...
    return Partial("_FrequencyLine", model);
}
```

So far par for the course.  **Now, things get interesting.**

As you can see, while our note name field is limited to only a single character, they can enter an invalid note name; musical notes range from A to G.  If a user enters anything from H-Z, that isn't a valid musical note, and thus should not generate a frequency!  In fact, a red error message should appear next to the note name field.

My `FrequencyLineViewModel` looks like this...

```
public enum NoteSign 
{
    Natural,
    Sharp,
    Flat
}

public class FrequencyLineViewModel : IValidatableObject
{
    [Required]
    public string NoteName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public NoteSign NoteSign { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Octave { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<string, float> FrequencyLookup = new Dictionary<string, float>{
        // Each note from A0 to G#0 has an associated frequency.  This lists 'em.
        // A full listing of the frequency table is not salient to this question.
    }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext context)
    {
        List<ValidationResult> results = new List<ValidationResult>();

        byte asciiCode = (byte) (NoteName.ToUpper())[0];
        if(asciiCode >= 72    // Between H and Z
           && asciiCode <= 90)
        {
            results.Add(new ValidationResult("(Invalid)", new []{"NoteName"}));
        }

        // Could add other validations here

        return results;
    }
}
```

So far in my tests, I have modified my **action**:

```
public void AddFrequencyLine(FrequencyLineViewModel model)
{
    model.IsValid = ModelState.IsValid;
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        model.CalculateFrequency();
        return PartialView("_NoteRecord", model);
    }

    // Need to change this...but to what?
    model.ErrorMessage = "Something is wrong!";
    return model;
}
```

...But I'm lost on how best to implement the fruits of a validation.  I set a breakpoint in my modified action on the `model.IsValid` check, and found that, in invalid cases such as an empty form, or a note from H-Z, that it is properly flagging as invalid; conversely, when entering a valid form, it works as intended.  But, I'm not interested in the 'works right' part; the invalid state has me stymied.

I could simply return the error message as I'm doing and use JavaScript in the success handler to figure out where to put it, if the IsValid property of the result is false (only happens on the invalid code path.)  The problem is, this defeats the purpose of the **success** handler; what's really happening is an error state.

So, at long last, to my **Question**: I'm trying to show some Validation Messages, but this setup dosen't lend itself to doing that.  What can I do to make this AJAX-based model validation present validation messages, without using my JavaScript success handler?

EDIT: The reason this is a question, is because our team wants to keep as much of our business logic on the server as possible; we're striving for a 'thin-client' setup. This means that the JavaScript will be only responsible 1) for GUI state, 2) for funneling data back to the server for processing, and 3) for receiving data from the server for presentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a precise answer for you but I wanted to ask: since your app is reliant on javascript already, why don't you validate the input client-side before making the ajax call? Best practices would be to validate both client-side before ajax and server-side just in case.

Perhaps you need to create a separate validation class that contains all of your rules (logic) and associated error messages which you could then reference in your model there.

Food for thought, sorry for a lack of real answer!

edit: I think I'm way off as far as addressing the actual question. You could consider always returning an object with an error property which is null when the input is valid but contains a relevant error message when the input is invalid. Then in your success handler you could just look for error != null and grab the error data there?

Comment: In our case, my team's leadership wants to keep as much of our business logic on the server as possible; we're striving for a 'thin-client' setup.  This means that the JavaScript will be only responsible 1) for GUI state, 2) for funneling data back to the server for processing, and 3) for receiving data from the server for presentation.

Comment: That makes sense. Is the confusion surrounding the naming of 'success' function in ajax call? I think the meaning is not "there was no error", but instead "I received a response from this ajax call." Therefore semantically there is no issue. You could return an object with a null error property, and always check for that in your 'success' function. If error isn't null then you know validation failed.